# How to one-time synchronise directories on Linux?

Tags: files, synchronization

A and B are directories. I'd like to copy every file in A that's not in B to B and remove every file in B that's not in A. The result should be equivalent to the result of `rm -r B/*; cp -r A/* B`, but I want to avoid unnecessary copying when there is only a small difference in the content of A and B. (Files are considered the same if they have the same content (name is an alternative).) How can I do this (optimally in the shell)?

Comment: To clarify, if there's a file `A/foo` and a file `B/foo` but they have different content, do you want to leave `B/foo` alone or to replace its content by the content of `A/foo`? Your rm+cp code does that, but your English description doesn't say that.

Answer (score 3):

The `rsync` command does exactly this:

```
rsync -av --delete srcdir/ destdir
```

(The trailing `/` in `srcdir/` is necessary.)

See [`man rsync`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html) for more options and for details on the above command.